# fromMap(dynamic message) が定義されていないと出る

Tags: flutter, dart

以下のように定義しています。

```
static LocationData fromMap(dynamic message) {
    final Map<dynamic, dynamic> dataMap = message;
}
```

しかし、mainファイルにて下記のようなコードを書くと 「fromMap」が定義されていないと出ます。どうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
locationData: LocationData.fromMap(data['position']!),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static LocationData fromMap(dynamic message) {
    final Map<dynamic, dynamic> dataMap = message;
}
```

この関数はリターンしていないです、リターンしないと何も起こらないです。